# Network Visualization - AdjacencyGraph - no overlapping vertices

Tags: plotting, manipulate, graphs-and-networks

I currently plotted a graph with the following code:

```
AdjacencyGraph[repindhallo2000c, 
 VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Placed[labels[[i]], Center], {i, 1, 56}], 
 VertexSize -> Table[j -> figures[[j]], {j, 1, 56}], ImageSize -> 600,
 EdgeStyle -> {Arrowheads[0.02]}]
```

It looks as follows:

[image: example1]

Now I have two questions which I could not solve so far:

1. How is it possible to separate the nodes that they not overlap? 
   As I use different sizes, I would like to show that the larger ones have more directed edges. Therefore I need them not to overlap.
2. As you can see on the bottom of the graph, apparently there are rows in `repindhallo2000c`which sum to zero. Hence there are vertices without any connection. Does anyone know how to delete them? Either directly out the adjacency graph or beforehand in the binary matrix.

---

Here is a small example:

```
list = List[{1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1,
     0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
    1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0,
     1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}];
head = List[{"a"}, {"b"}, {"c"}, {"d"}, {"e"}, {"f"}, {"g"}, {"h"}, \
{"i"}, {"j"}, {"k"}, {"l"}, {"m"}, {"n"}, {"o"}];
vertexsize = N[(Total[list]/Total[Total[list]])*15];
AdjacencyGraph[list, 
 VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Placed[head[[i]], Center], {i, 1, 15}], 
 VertexSize -> Table[j -> vertexsize[[j]], {j, 1, 15}]]
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks for update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is it possible to separate the nodes that they not overlap?

I do not think that there is an automatic method. I usually scale them manually until there is no overlap. At the same time, I usually increase the size of the graphics ([`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html)). Text labels do not scale with the image, they always stay the same size. I try to increase the image size until a text label fits inside of the smallest node.

It often helps to define the vertex size as `{"Nearest", s}` (see [`VertexSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexSize.html) under Details).

> Hence there are vertices without any connection. Does anyone know how to delete them?

```
Pick[VertexList[g], VertexDegree[g], 0]
```

gives you the isolated vertices. You can [`VertexDelete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexDelete.html) them.

You may want `VertexInDegree` or `VertexOutDegree` instead of directed graphs.

Answer (score 3):

> *... vertices without any connection. Does anyone know how to delete them?*

You can also use [`VertexDelete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexDelete.html) directly, using a pattern in the second argument:

```
VertexDelete[g, _?(VertexDegree[g, #] === 0 &)]
```

Or, [`Subgraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Subgraph.html) combined with [`KCoreComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/KCoreComponents.html):

```
Subgraph[g, KCoreComponents[g, 1]]
```

For the example:

```
 g = Graph[Range[7], {1 <->  2, 2 <-> 3,  3 <-> 1, 3<-> 4}, 
      VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexShapeFunction -> None,
      VertexLabelStyle -> Large, ImagePadding -> 5]
```

[image]

```
 VertexDelete[g, _?(VertexDegree[g, #] === 0 &)]
 Subgraph[g, KCoreComponents[g, 1], Options[g]]
```

both give

[image]

Comment: You answer lots of graph questions. Have you tried out [IGraph/M](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/)?  Let me know if you have any comments on it.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I haven't tried IGraphM.  I am still on version 9.1 :(